# Android : display foreground (and views) in a camera preview in order to make an old camera back look

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, surfaceview

I've got some troubles with Camera preview (in a FrameLayout).
I want to achieve something like this :

https://lh4.ggpht.com/aFPHmlYNaSAAJV2er2inD9dlXS61Sj-V1qyYeCpfgMCPY18kgdQEdIOyWkaXOlWeAkM=h900-rw or this : https://lh4.ggpht.com/_OkN-O2mb3s4VO6QoSj15cTdzTBic_Ji8-ZGg16PmvfFUNWpQHfaZuN6ofwPWOHhr34=h900-rw

But so far, all I was able to do :
- a full screen preview in a FrameLayout
- a tiny preview misplaced (I want it centered horizontally and at 40 dp of the top)

Here is my layout so far :

`<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_app_photo_transparent"
        tools:context="jmf.net.testsapp.CameraActivity" >
     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/master_layout"
        />
</FrameLayout>`

The first FrameLayout is where I put the nine patch drawable which must recover some of camera preview.
The second FrameLayout (id/master_layout) is the one where I create a SurfaceView to display camera preview.

But when I try this, I've got the camera preview in the bottom left corner.

So I guess I started badly.

Here is my question : How can I manage layout and camera preview in order to have something like in the pictures below ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad to see you found your answer. Instead of adding "solved" to the title, you should accept the answer that solved it - even if it is your own, that's perfectly OK here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="3">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_0_0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_0_1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_0_2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_1_0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/master_layout"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/master_layout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/master_layout" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/master_layout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_1_2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/master_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/master_layout" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_2_0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_2_1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/master_layout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:background="@drawable/slice_2_2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView6" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for bothering.